# Why is $N\cap A_n$ a normal subgroup of $A_n$ for $N\unlhd S_n$.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $N$ is a normal proper subgroup of $S_n$, why does it follow that $N\cap A_n\unlhd A_n$? I understand that the intersection of two normal subgroups is normal in $S_n$, but why $A_n$?

Answer (score 1):

So you understand that $g(N\cap A_n)g^{-1}=N\cap A_n$ holds for every $g\in S_n$? Then you cannot doubt that it holds for every $g\in A_n$ ...